# Enable Add-to-page permission for Sign In portlet only for portal Administrator in Liferay portal

Tags: permissions, liferay, portlet

I need to **disable** Add-to-page permisson for **Sign In** portlet for **Site Administrator**. This permission should be enabled only for portal **Administrator** role.

I have tried to uncheck all permissions in Plugins Configuration for Sign in portlet for all roles but it doesn't help.

Sign in portlet is still visible for **site administrator** role.

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Thansk a lot!

BTW: We are using Liferay 6.2 CE.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to remove other roles from portlet permission, in order to remove "Add to Page" permission from other roles.

```
1.Login as Administrator
2.Go to Control Panel -> Plugins Configuration (make sure Portlet Plugin is selected on top menu)
3.Search for your portlet name and click it
4.In the Permissions table remove all Roles less then Administrator Save
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I have tried your steps but Site administrator can still see that portlet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify permission of default liferay sign in portlet, then customize the sign-in portlet and modify the permissions.

The original permissions is mentioned inside ROOT/WEB-INF/portlet-custom.xml file with portlet-id=58.